# French dependency parsing using CoreNLP

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

I am following the example in this [link](http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/cmdline.html). I have downloaded the french jar from [here](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/stanford-french-corenlp-2016-01-14-models.jar). When I call it as follows,

`java -mx1g -cp "*" edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -props StanfordCoreNLP-french.properties -annotators tokenize,ssplit,pos,depparse -file french.txt -outputFormat conllu`

I always see it loads a english dep-parser model instead of french.

`Loading depparse model file: edu/stanford/nlp/models/parser/nndep/english_UD.gz ...
PreComputed 100000, Elapsed Time: 1.341 (s)`

Is this a bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update -- I found that the default properties file does not specify a depparse model. So now I give it my own config file and now it works.

```
annotators = tokenize, ssplit, pos, depparse, parse

tokenize.language = fr

pos.model = edu/stanford/nlp/models/pos-tagger/french/french.tagger

parse.model = edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/frenchFactored.ser.gz

depparse.model = edu/stanford/nlp/models/parser/nndep/UD_French.gz
```

Comment: hi! I have the same problem and although I use the same properties file with you (provided above ) I still get the `Loading depparse model file: edu/stanford/nlp/models/parser/nndep/english_UD.gz` output. Did you do any renaming operation or something like that? When I downloaded  french jar, I put it into `stanford-corenlp-full-2015-12-09` folder.  Did you do the same thing?

Comment: I solved my problem, you have to give a name different than the `StanfordCoreNLP-french.properties` if you want to prepare your own config file