# German corenlp model defaulting to english models

Tags: server, nlp, stanford-nlp, stanford-nlp-server

I use the following command to serve a  corenlp server for German language models which are downloaded as jar in the classpath , but it does not output german tags or parse but loads only english models:

```
 java -mx4g -cp "*" edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer   -props ./german.prop
```

german.prop contents:

```
annotators = tokenize, ssplit, pos, depparse, parse

tokenize.language = de

pos.model = edu/stanford/nlp/models/pos-tagger/german/german-hgc.tagger

ner.model = edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/german.hgc_175m_600.crf.ser.gz
ner.applyNumericClassifiers = false
ner.useSUTime = false

parse.model = edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/germanFactored.ser.gz
depparse.model = edu/stanford/nlp/models/parser/nndep/UD_German.gz
```

client command:

```
wget --post-data ' Meine Mutter ist aus Wuppertal' 'localhost:9000/?properties"="{"tokenize.whitespace":"true","annotators":"tokenize, ssplit, pos, depparse, parse","outputFormat":"text","tokenize.language" :"de" ,
 "pos.model":" edu/stanford/nlp/models/pos-tagger/german/german-hgc.tagger",
"depparse.model" : "edu/stanford/nlp/models/parser/nndep/UD_German.gz",
"parse.model" : "edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/germanFactored.ser.gz"

 }' -O -
```

I get following incorrect output:

```
 {"dep":"dep","governor":4,"governorGloss":"aus","dependent":5,"dependentGloss":"Wuppertal"}],"openie":[{"subject":"Wuppertal","subjectSpan":[4,5],"relation":"is ist aus of","relationSpan":[2,4],"object":"Meine Mutter","objectSpan":[0,2]}],"tokens":[{"index":1,"word":"Meine","originalText":"Meine","lemma":"Meine","characterOffsetBegin":1,"characterOffsetEnd":6,"pos":"NNP","ner":"PERSON","speaker":"PER0","before":" ","after":" "},{"index":2,"word":"Mutter","originalText":"Mutter","lemma":"Mutter","characterOffsetBegin":7,"characterOffsetEnd":13,"pos":"NNP","ner":"PERSON","speaker":"PER0","before":" ","after":" "},{"index":3,"word":"ist","originalText":"ist","lemma":"ist","characterOffsetBegin":14,"characterOffsetEnd":17,"pos":"NN","ner":"O","speaker":"PER0","before":" ","after":" "},{"index":4,"word":"aus","originalText":"aus","lemma":"aus","characterOffsetBegin":18,"characterOffsetEnd":21,"pos":"NN","ner":"O","speaker":"PER0","before":" ","after":" "},{"index":5,"word":"Wuppertal","originalText":"Wuppertal","lemma":"Wuppertal","characterOffsetBegin":22,"characterOffsetEnd":31,"pos":"NNP","ner":"LOCATI100%[==========================================================================>] 2,
```

in the server log I see it loads english models eventhough it lists german models on startup:

```
pos.model=edu/stanford/nlp/models/pos-tagger/ge...
parse.model=edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/ger...
tokenize.language=de
depparse.model=edu/stanford/nlp/models/parser/nndep/...
annotators=tokenize, ssplit, pos, depparse, parse
Starting server on port 9000 with timeout of 5000 milliseconds.
StanfordCoreNLPServer listening at /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9000
[/203.:61563] API call w/annotators tokenize,ssplit,pos,depparse
Die Katze liegt auf der Matte.
[pool-1-thread-1] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator tokenize
[pool-1-thread-1] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.TokenizerAnnotator - TokenizerAnnotator: No tokenizer type provided. Defaulting to PTBTokenizer.
[pool-1-thread-1] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator ssplit
[pool-1-thread-1] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator pos
Reading POS tagger model from edu/stanford/nlp/models/pos-tagger/english-left3words/english-left3words-distsim.tagger ... done [1.5 sec].
[pool-1-thread-1] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator depparse
Loading depparse model file: edu/stanford/nlp/models/parser/nndep/english_UD.gz ...
PreComputed 100000, Elapsed Time: 1.396 (s)
```

The following question for same error in french models also points to the same problem but even after following , it does not resolve the problem for the server case, I am able to get the correct output without using the server and just using the `edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP command` , it is the server command `edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer` which defaults to english:
[French dependency parsing using CoreNLP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36223002/french-dependency-parsing-using-corenlp#)

Comment: is it '-props' or -'serverProperties' ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There have been some issues with getting the foreign language stuff to work on the server.

If you use the latest release available at our GitHub site, it should work.

The GitHub site is here: https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP

That link has instructions for building a jar with the latest version of the code.

I ran this command on some sample German text and it looks like it works fine:

```
wget --post-data '<sample german text>' 'localhost:9000/?properties={"pipelineLanguage":"german","annotators":"tokenize,ssplit,pos,ner,parse", "parse.model":"edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/germanFactored.ser.gz","tokenize.language":"de","pos.model":"edu/stanford/nlp/models/pos-tagger/german/german-hgc.tagger", "ner.model":"edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/german.hgc_175m_600.crf.ser.gz", "ner.applyNumericClassifiers":"false", "ner.useSUTime":"false"}' -O -
```

I should note that the neural net German dependency parser is completely broken and we are working on fixing it soon, so you should just use the German settings I specified in that command.

More info on the server can be found here: http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/corenlp-server.html

Comment: Thanks, its working now even in the published version, the new thing here is "pipelineLanguage":"german" which is documented nowhere!, also corenlp server interface should also be modified to give the correct visual representation